# error: symbol 'grub_is_lockdown' not found while installing ubuntu-20.04.4 from USB ISO

Tags: boot, usb, grubrescue, ubuntu-drivers

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I have been trying to install ubuntu-20.04.4 for our tower (V100) booting from USB. Unfortunately, getting the following error.

error: symbol 'grub_is_lockdown' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

I've attempted to use various ports and two new USB devices, thinking that there might be an issue with either the port or the USB. However, I'm still encountering the above-mentioned error.

I did the set root = md/mdboot/grub and set root = md/mdboot and insmood normal (ls showed all the ssds and md/mdboot)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drwn6.png)

Secure Boot is “disabled”

Grateful if any alternative suggestions, please. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using that updated media?  On fully upgraded systems (using Secure uEFI) you can only successfully boot 20.04.6 media as 20.04.4 is using a *revoked* key..   I'd try the currently valid media; and ensure you performed ISO validation & correctly wrote the ISO to media (*you can cause the media to get the error you appear to have when its written incorrectly*)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, guiverc. I appreciate the information. At the biology lab, we use a machine to sequence DNA, and we have attached the sequencer to V100 GPU. Currently, we are using version 20.04.4, which is compatible with the software. Recently, this tower has got a new motherboard. Since then experiencing this grub rescue error when tried to boot the GPU. However, I will also check with the provider to confirm this. To create a bootable USB, I used Rufus to burn the ISO file.